# Suggestion for an article or book

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to get acquainted with rigorous definition of real exponents via limits of rational exponents. Can you suggest an article or a chapter in some textbook with topic about this ? All the posts on stackexchange on this topic I read, don`t really dive into proofs. And I could not find something with all the proofs on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there are some problems in Spivak's book Calculus that take this approach to defining $b^x$.

Comment: check pages 258-259 of this book: http://math.kennesaw.edu/~jlewin/CUP/marielle.pdf